# Issue with IFrame - Selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

Consider a webpage contains a IFrame, in that IFrame it contains only one
text box and a close button is present outside the IFrame.
According to this scenario,
how to click on the close button by filling in some values in Iframe text box

i.e First thing is to select the Frame using the command selenium.selectFrame("1_frame"); and
enter the text using the command selenium.type("id=name","test");
Problem here is,I need to click on the close button which is present outside the Frame.

What command should I use to click on the close button, present outside the frame?
How should I bring the focus to close button ?

Can any one help me out!
Thanks in advance .

Comment: provide html of close button it'll be easy for us to give exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

After entering value in text box set focus to main window if close button is not part of IFRAME. You can do this by selectWindow("null") command.

Answer (score 1):

Use Xpath or css path of close button and then perform click(Xpath).
If you are using firefox you can use firebug to get xpath or css path.
If it is not in iframe u can even use click(id or name)

Answer (score 0):

if your IFRAMEs are Static then it can be handled easily.
If dynamic iframe present then You have to work from framework label.